# Laravel Backpack select2_from_ajax_multiple with support to add new records

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

Is there an easy way to use `select2_from_ajax_multiple` or similar `n-n` relation field in `Laravel Backpack` which will support also creating new records if they do not exist?

What I am trying to achieve is `tags` functionality, but without the need to go to the other model to define new tags and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such functionality built-in, no. There's [a long talk](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/591) about why a general solution is more complicated than it seems. It's a feature that Backpack most certainly will have, but it will probably be in Backpack 4, not the current one.

I'm afraid you're going to have to [create a custom field type](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-fields#section-custom-field-types) starting from `select2_from_ajax_multiple` if you want this functionality now.